# Django Как работает представление формы?

Tags: python, django, view

Прошу объяснить дословно, как работает представление формы в Django, в книге этому примеру формы уделено мало внимания и мне совсем не ясно следующее:

1) Зачем нужно создавать эти атрибуты внутри BbCreateView: `template_name, form_class, success_url`, если они нигде не вызываются? Или Django их как-то сам подтягивает из класса?

2) Зачем нужно переопределять метод `get_context_data`? Для чего там `super()`

Код в представлении приложения (views.py):

```
class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    form_class = BbForm
    success_url = '/bboard/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
        return context
```

Код используемых моделей:

```
class BbForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bb
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'price', 'rubric', )

class Rubric(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True, verbose_name = 'Название')
```

[image: Скриншот формы]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё это - "магия" Django.

Фреймворк сам подтянет всё необходимое, а именно шаблон (`template_name`), форму (`form_class`), а после создания объекта перенаправит на нужный URL (`success_url`).

Метод `get_context_data` Вы переопределяете для того, чтобы дополнительно добавить в него рубрики (`rubrics`). Тут ключевой слово - "дополнительно". То есть, мы не хотим, чтобы метод, который Django наколдовал для нас, полностью переопределился и потерялся.
Для этого мы используем функцию `super()`, которая позволяет обратиться к родительскому классу и вызываем его метод `get_context_data`.
Простыми словами, мы дополняем родительский метод.